# Sharepoint Online - Recover column from lists of project sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, column, disaster-recovery

I have a site collection with a lot of subsites attached to projects (each subsite is a site created by a project). Those subsites has a list with its fields.

I executed a PowerShell script that excluded some columns of this list and I want to recover this columns to get the data back or perhaps a way to get this data that was lost in the execution of the script. I used to following code inside a loop:

```
if($fields[$index].CanBeDeleted)
{
    $fields[$index].DeleteObject()
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

If there is no way to recover the field, someone has some idea how can I get the data of the excluded columns back or any other solution? Maybe a way to do some restore of data(subsite) in another URL to not overwrite the actual site?

Someone has an idea how can i solve this?

PS: I am using SharePoint Online. I have no access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online has no backup nor restore out-of-the-box. You would have to contact Microsoft support but I doubt that they would help you.

Only items, lists, sites and site collections can be restored that were deleted and are still in Recycle Bin. You cannot restore data from deleted column.

This message pops out when you try to delete column in UI:

> This column will be removed and all the data stored in the column will be permanently deleted. Are you sure you want to delete this column?

Sorry, but its too late.